# Modal doesn't come with input's values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, modal-dialog

I have to use modals in my project. But unfortunately it does not work well.
On the page, when I click on the Add New Role button, everything goes right. But then when I click on the role edit button, the modal is displayed with blank values. While the IDs are successfully sent to the action.
After that when you reload the page, and first click on the edit role button, the modal will not display at all. At the same time, if you click the Add New Role button again, the modal is successfully displayed and everything is OK. At the same time, if you click the role edit button again, the modal will be displayed again in blank. (Just as before the IDs were successfully sent to the action but not found). I think this problem is related to two things:

1. The problem is with the action (maybe the code I wrote didn't send
   the values well)
2. The problem may be that the following `JQuery` codes is not
   performing well:

> Jquery (file name: application-role-index.js):

```
(function ($) {
    function RoleList() {
        var $this = this;

        function initilizeModel() {
            $("#modal-action-application-role").on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {

            }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
            });
        }
        $this.init = function () {
            initilizeModel();
        }
    }
    $(function () {
        var self = new RoleList();
        self.init();
    })
}(jQuery))
```

Anyway i hope you can help me. Here is the code I will use for this section:

---

> Action in `'RoleListController'`:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddEditRole(string Id)
    {
        RoleListViewModel model = new RoleListViewModel();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
        {
            ApplicationRole applicationRole = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);
            if (applicationRole != null)
            {
                model.Id = applicationRole.Id;
                model.Name = applicationRole.Name;
                model.Explanation = applicationRole.Explanation;
            }
            return PartialView("_AddAndEditAppRole", model);
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_AddAndEditAppRole");
        }
    }
```

---

> The View page i'm using modal:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="showaddrole" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="AddEditRole" data-target="#modal-action-application-role">افزودن نقش جدید</a>
</div>

<table dir="rtl" class="table table-bordered table-striped myTable table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Explanation)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.NumberOfUsers)</th>
            <th>عملیات</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var role in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@role.Id</td>
                <td>@role.Name</td>
                <td>@role.Explanation</td>
                <td>@role.NumberOfUsers</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-info myTableIC" asp-route-id="@role.Id" asp-action="AddEditRole" data-target="#modal-action-application-role" data-toggle="modal">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger myTableIC" asp-route-id="@role.Id" asp-action="DeleteRole">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@Html.Partial("_Modal", new BootstrapModel { ID = "modal-action-application-role", Size = ModalSize.Medium })
@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/modal-js/application-role-index.js"></script>
}
```

I have prepared a short video of how my program works so you can move forward with a better understanding:
[You can find that by this link...](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8371595834/Untitled_Project.gif)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest a solution at first create a div block with a unique id

```
<div id="popup"></div>
```

than use ajax to call the action like this :

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("AddEditRole")',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#popup").html(result);
                $("#popup-addRole").modal("show");
            }
        });

    });
```

then create an partiel view of popup with the id of model is popup-addRole something like this

```
       <div class="modal" id="popup-edt" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:50%;">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
//add your form here 
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

don't forget to add model you want to use 
i hope that fix the problem